# Como retornar apenas 10 registros em firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

Desejo retornar apenas um numero exato de registros do firebase, mas não sei como deveria ser feito, existe algum meio?

Comment: Olá thiago poste o seu código que desenvolveu até então. Tbm veja este link se tiver interesse https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para retornar apenas uma quantidade X de registros, utilize as funções *limitToFirst* ou *limitToLast*.

*limitToFirst* irá retornar os primeiros X registros e *limitToLast* os últimos X registros, com base na ordernação dos dados aplicada.

Por exemplo, a consulta abaixo irá retornar os 2 últimos registros, considerando a orderm pela coluna *weight*.

```
curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="weight"&limitToLast=2&print=pretty'
```

Agora para fazer esse

> desejo pegar de maneira dinâmica a cada 2 registros

que você escreveu nos comentários, dá pra usar as funções *startAt* e *endAt*.
Considerando que seus registros estarão ordenados de acordo com um determinado valor, um *startAt* igual a X e *endAt* igual a Y irá retornar os registros a partir do valor de ordenação X até o valor Y.

Então nesse caso você precisará ordernar seus dados com base em uma sequência numérica (1, 2, 3, ...) e fazer *startAt=1&endAt=2*, *startAt=3&endAt=5*, e assim por diante.

Veja os links da documentação que podem ajudar: [FILTRAGEM COMPLEXA](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-complex-queries)

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência. As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada.

Comment: Ok, irei atualizar a resposta.